how to declare a class in a '.ps1' file?
I want to provide a list of allowed names to the name parameter, so that the user can tab into them.
I have come up with the following:
Param(
    [ValidateSet([foo])]
    [string]$Name
    )
    $name

Class foo : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator{
    [string[]] GetValidValues(){
    return [string[]] ("cat", "dog", "fish")
    }}
    

Typing .\myScript.ps1 -name  and then pressing tab nothing is suggested. running .\myScript.ps1 returns an error:
Line |
   3 |      [ValidateSet([foo])]
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to find type [foo].

I can do this exact set up in a psm1 file or just as a standard function and it works. I thought of moving the class into the top of the script file but this not allowed due to param() needing to be the first line.
Is there a way around this issue? Am on pwsh 7.4

This is what modules are for in some extent. The class needs to be defined and loaded before the script executes. If you want to do runtime set then use the string array overload

@SantiagoSquarzon hmm, makes sense. I am tyring to keep up ".ps1" with ".psm1", I guess its not practical. I though of using module <module with class> but again this runs into that hard rule of param() needing to be on the first line. By the way, what do you mean by  "If you want to do runtime set then use existing decoration ValidateSet"

I mean that you can just do [ValidateSet('cat', 'dog', 'fish')] for your specific example.

@Ralf_Reddings params(...) does not need to be on the first line, it just has to precede the body of your script/function

@Ralf_Reddings: Note that you syntactically can place a using statement before a param(...) block, but doing so doesn't help in your case:  using module and using assembly statements are only executed at runtime, whereas a class needs to already be loaded at parse time in order to be usable inside a param(...) block.

There is no workaround for what you're attempting: A PowerShell script with parameters that makes use of the ValidateSetAttribute(Type valuesGeneratorType) overload which also defines the IValidateSetValuesGenerator inheriting type in the same file.
You can either define a function in the script and dot source it:
class foo : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
    [string[]] GetValidValues() {
        return [string[]] ('cat', 'dog', 'fish')
    }
}

function Get-Foo {
    Param(
        [ValidateSet([foo])]
        [string]$Name
    )
}

Use the ValidateSetAttribute(params string[] validValues) overload for runtime evaluation:
Param(
    [ValidateSet('cat', 'dog', 'fish')]
    [string]$Name
)

Dot source the IValidateSetValuesGenerator inheriting class before calling the script:
PS ..\pwsh> . .\FooValidatorClass.ps1
PS ..\pwsh> .\myFooScript.ps1 <TAB>

Or use a module as you already know.

This is a good summary for a possible number of workarounds. I will certainly come back to reffer to it in the future. Cheers
